# Conversion of string array into another string array on the basis of a parameter

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have another question.

How to convert a string array to another string array on the basis of a parameter?

```
string[] x={ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G" };
string[] y=new string[number];

for(int I=0;i<number;i++)
{
y=x[i];
}
```

The above implementation shows error.

If the parameter number is 3, then array y should have A,B,C,D.

Basically on the basis of a parameter, I want to generate another array from the parent array

I know this question is not too high-tech but I am not able to get around it.

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Anurag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shows an error because you have declared `int I`, but tried to access `i` and also, you need to access `y` using an indexer:

```
string[] x={ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G" };
string[] y=new string[number];

for(int i=0;i<number;i++)
{
    y[i] = x[i];
}
```

Will work fine, however you may need to increment `number` by one if you want number to be `3` yet store the first 4 values...

Comment: Thank you Mr.Graham..Now I get it..it wasn't a case of case-sensitivity. I was not using 'i' as an index parameter when accessing y. Silly me...

Answer (score 4):

`Array.Copy` has an overload called [`Array.Copy Method (Array, Array, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> **Copies a range of elements** from an Array starting at the first element
>   and pastes them into another Array starting at the first element.

```
Array.Copy(x, y, number + 1);
```

For a full example;

```
string[] x = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G" };
string[] y = new string[4];
Array.Copy(x, y, 4);
foreach (var item in y)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Output will be;

```
A
B
C
D
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/e8J2KW)</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you..i didn't know about Array.Copy method.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to for loop. You can do it with `LINQ`

```
string[] y = x.Select(item => item).Take(number+1).ToArray();
```

Comment: This is not the most efficient method. However, it has the advantage that you don't need to care about number+1 being bigger then x size.

Comment: @Cosmin, OP didn't say anything about that.If that is the case the for loop might be throw exception too.He should check number

Comment: Thank you...I will try the solution

Comment: That's what I'm saying. By using Take you won't get that exception. You will just get a smaller array so you should no longer be concerned about the check.

Answer (score 0):

First you need a bigger array if number=3 should give you A,B,C,D

```
string[] x={ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G" };
string[] y=new string[number+1];
```

And use [Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to copy the elements

```
Array.Copy(x, y, number+1);
```